# AttributeError: 'HParams' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: tensor2tensor

When we use tensor2tensor decoding, we have encountered this problem.

```
t2t-decoder \
  --data_dir=train_data_enzh \
  --problem=translate_enzh_wmt32k \
  --model=transformer \
  --hparams_set=transformer_base \
  --output_dir=enzhdata/model \
  --decode_hparams="beam_size=4,alpha=0.6" \
  --decode_from_file=decode_this.txt \
  --decode_to_file=translation.en
```

**the error is:**
AttributeError: 'HParams' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: You'll need to be more descriptive than this. Please provide some of the trace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you are using an old version of TensorFlow. Upgrade and you should see the problem disappear.